# Math function to round up the values to .0 or .5

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I round numbers up to the nearest whole *or* to the nearest half?

For Example:

```
> 23.15 --> 23.5
> 23.56 --> 24.0
```

The rounding functions I know about are `floor` and `ceil`, but those only round to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to round up, to a multiple of 0.5? Am I understanding that correctly?

```
double RoundUpToPointFive(double d)
{
    return Math.Ceiling(d * 2) / 2;
}
```

Comment: This intrigued me, found that the 2 is found by doing 100 / 50, because 50 is half of 100, which is the same as .5. Could be helpful if you want to alter the behavior of the rounding to say 0.1 by doing 100 / 10.

Comment: Is it worth it? You use 2 instead of an explicit significance value. Why not `var significance = 0.5;` then `return Math.Ceiling(d / significance) * significance;`

Answer (score 4):

Why don't try this one, with any significance you want in the precision:

```
public double Ceiling(double value, double significance)
{
    if ((value % significance) != 0)
    {
        return ((int)(value / significance) * significance) + significance;
    }

    return Convert.ToDouble(value);
}
```

Usage:

```
var d1 = Ceiling(23.15, 0.5); // 23.5
var d2 = Ceiling(23.56, 0.5); // 24.0
```

This function of Ceiling is used by Microsoft Excel, and to match this calculation i devised this algorithm.

Reference: [Ceiling and Floor functions like Microsoft Excel in .NET](http://furqan-safdar.blogspot.com/2012/05/ceiling-and-floor-functions-like.html)

Comment: Very nice. Upon looking at your example I realized you can make it round down by simply removing the + significance part.

Comment: Yes that is already done under the mentioned link, for Floor calculation. :)

Comment: **! Error !** `Ceiling(-150, 100)` returns `0`, expected `-100`; `Ceiling(-50, 100)` returns `100`, expected `0`; etc. [DotNetFiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nFSqjV)

Comment: @FurqanSafdar but I expect you to be stubborn and invent something else instead of the boring `Math.Ceiling(value / significance) * significance;` Yes?))

Comment: @FurqanSafdar Your Floor also has troubles with negative values. The following is remedy for me `Math.Floor(value / significance) * significance`. May I be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The quick and dirty way:

Multiply by 2, ceiling, and divide by 2.  Quick and easy to understand, but this will fail on edge cases due to number overflow.

A more robust method is to cut off everything before the decimal before evaluating the round with the method above, and add the result to the whole number you cut off.

Answer (score 0):

David's method pretty much seals it, but here is another lengthier way.

```
double dbNum = 3.44;
double dbNumModified = 3.44 + 0.5;
dbNumModified = Math.Floor(dbNum);
if(dbNumModified < dbNum)
{
   dbNumModified += 0.5;
}
return dbNumModified;
```

Comment: My assumption

`3.0 --> 3.0,
3.1 --> 3.5,
3.6 --> 4.0`

If what you said is what the user wants, then all he needs to do is replace `<` with `<=`